# Can't put canvas side by side with other elements using grid manager

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
class Main(tk.Frame):

    w = 300
    h = 300

    def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent

        self.l1 = tk.Label(self, text="Iterations").grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.l2 = tk.Label(self, text="angle").grid(column=0,row=1)
        self.l3 = tk.Label(self, text="axiom").grid(column=0,row=2)
        self.l4 = tk.Label(self, text="rule1").grid(column=0,row=3)
        self.l5 = tk.Label(self, text="rule2").grid(column=0, row=4)
        self.l6 = tk.Label(self, text="constants").grid(column=0, row=5)

        self.e1 = tk.Entry(self, text="Iterations").grid(column=1,row=0)
        self.e2 = tk.Entry(self, text="angle").grid(column=1,row=1)
        self.e3 = tk.Entry(self, text="axiom").grid(column=1,row=2)
        self.e4 = tk.Entry(self, text="rule1").grid(column=1,row=3)
        self.e5 = tk.Entry(self, text="rule2").grid(column=1, row=4)
        self.e6 = tk.Entry(self, text="constants").grid(column=1, row=5)

        self.cv = tk.Canvas(width=self.w, height=self.h, bg='white')
        self.cv.grid(column=2, rowspan=5)

        # self.render_image()
        self.grid()
```

I want my entry boxes and canvas stay side by side, but labels and entry boxes are drawn below the canvas for some reason. I get this;

[image: Imgur]

How can I show them side by side instead?

Comment: BTW: using `e6 = tk.Entry(...).grid(...)` you get result of `grid()` in `e6` but `grid()` always return `None`. Do  `e6 = tk.Entry(...)` and `e6.grid(...)`

Comment: You forget set parent for `Canvas`. Other elements belong to `self` `Label(self,...)`, `Entry(self,...)`. Try `Canvas(self, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified a row for your `Canvas`:

```
self.cv.grid(column=2, rowspan=5)
```

Just update this to include the top row:

```
self.cv.grid(column=2, rowspan=5, row=0)
```

Also `rowspan` should likely be 6 not 5.